# How to make the snake to pass from one side of the screen and come out the opposite side?

Tags: c#, collision-detection

How do I code the left and right collision, and also tell me how I can set the collision of snake according to the form size.

If i want to change or maximize the form, snake should collide with the ending boundaries of the form ..

[image]

Comment: Please use the 'copy' and 'paste' features of your computer to copy code to your posts, it takes much less effort than taking a screenshot and uploading it here. You should you that feature along with the 'code sample' feature of the question and answer edit boxes.

Comment: And this is worthy of a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer one of your problems enough to allow you to fill in the rest. I'm a C++ developer, so I'm not gonna be your best source of information. (For the heads up)

To collision detect the border of the window, you'd say something like:

```
int xMin = 0, xMax = this.width;
int yMin = 0, yMax = this.height;

if (player.x <= xMin) {
    // Arguments go here for if object player has passed the left of the window border.
} else if (player.y >= yMax) {
    // Arguments here for if object player is passing the bottom of the screen.
}
```

So that's all I've got, but I hope it helps. Good luck! I only know that information bc I had to make a pong game in C++ using Windows Forms, it's extremely hard, and it had TONS of bugs.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh, and forgot to mention, welcome to programming with C#!

Comment: How long have you been doing C# for?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this whilst learning basics of c++, its one of the first things we had to do for collision detection so hopefully I can be of some use

Youll want to store the width and height of your screen in variables, and then perform a collision check to determine whether or not you have touched the screen and set the snakes position to, for example, the same on the x axis but at the other side of the screen.

This is a basic example from my work

```
if (object.position.X > window.width)
{
    object.position.X = 0;
}
else if (object.position.X + object.sourceRect.Width < 0)
{
    object.position.X = this.Width - object.sourceRect.Width;
}
```

By using this.Width, even if the form changes in size, the check should still work

Alls this is doing is the X axis checks, but you also need to take into account the width of the object that is going to be colliding, not just its x and y positions

From what youve got, you seem to already have the collision checks implemented. All's you should need to do now is set the snakes position to the other side of the screen, and from whatt I've shown you, and a bit of trial and error, it shouldn't be too hard:)